# md5sum mismatch (954ba1b87d3a20757aed046b5b4078f1 != 4b2834b201a8e322d0b941a6eec7557c) on build/gmapping_r39.tar.gz; aborting

Tags: navigation, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to install slam_gmapping package, but when I type rosmake, one error happens.

d5sum mismatch (954ba1b87d3a20757aed046b5b4078f1 != 4b2834b201a8e322d0b941a6eec7557c) on build/gmapping_r39.tar.gz; aborting

I have researched but I could not solve the problem. Anyone have a idea of how I can fix this?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/110456/md5sum-mismatch-(954ba1b87d3a20757aed046b5b4078f1-!=-4b2834b201a8e322d0b941a6eec7557c)-on-build/gmapping_r39.tar.gz;-aborting/) by [alexandre](https://answers.ros.org/users/9926/alexandre/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-12-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How are you trying to install gmapping?
It looks like your download is being truncated. If you're compiling from source you should remove that file and try again.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-12-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0